# How to pass the id of a data for edit in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have got a task to do edit the value of a data. For that I create a `edit_userlist` page and created the code for editing.But by running I got an error it shows like this

```
Couldn't find User without an ID
```

url of this link is: `http://localhost:3000/edit_userlist.1`

My controller page is

```
def edit_userlist
   @user = User.find(params[:id])
 end
```

My index page for edit is

```
<% @users.each do |user| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= user.name %></td>
    <td><%= user.age %></td>
    <td><%= user.country %></td>
    <td><%= user.state %></td>
    <td><%= user.email %></td>
    <td><%= user.phone %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', user %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_userlist_path(user) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', user, :method => :delete, :data => { :confirm => 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

My edit_userlist page is

```
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
  <% if @user.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@user.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this user from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @user.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :age %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :age %>

  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :country %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :country %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :state %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :state %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :email %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :email %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :phone %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :phone %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

I gave proper routing to the page. My `routes.rb` page is

```
match '/edit_userlist/' => 'users#edit_userlist', :as => :edit_userlist
```

How can I pass the id to get edited the value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

change your route to

```
match '/edit_userlist/:id' => 'users#edit_userlist', :as => :edit_userlist
```